# Is the Chronomancer Wizard's Rewind feature triggered if their spell is counterspelled?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, class-feature, wizard, counterspelling

The [Chronomancer](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Wizard%20Chronomancer) wizard archetype gains the ability to reclaim ineffective spells using the Rewind feature:

> As an immediate action after **losing a spell due to a failed concentration check or after casting a spell that had no effect (such as due to successful saving throws, a failed caster level check to overcome spell resistance, or other immunities)**, the chronomancer can expend a number of points from his temporal pool equal to half the spell’s level (minimum 1) to immediately prepare the spell again, as if it had not been cast. Any material components expended in the original casting remain expended, as are actions used to cast the original spell.

Usually, this is pretty easy to judge... Failed your check vs. SR? Works. Enemy Saved on a *negates* spell? Works. Hit your ally who it did affect? Doesn't work.

However, is it valid to use this ability if an enemy [counterspells](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Counterspells&Category=Casting%20Spells) your attempted spell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counterspell rules state that succesful counterspell ends with:

> both spells automatically negate each other with no other results

The spell was cast at caster's action, and was negated later, using readied action of the counterspelling caster, with no other results.

Thus, it meets the *"casting a spell that had no effect"* pretty well. Spell casting happened. It had to to trigger readied counterspell. And there was no effect.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding, you're saying that yes, Rewind can be used when a spell is Counterspelled?

Comment: Yes, because it meets both requirements, "casting a spell" and "has no effect".

Comment: So, just to play advocate, you're saying that triggering a counterspell, expending the other caster's action and spell, would not be considered an "effect". Are there any rules to support that, or are you just going by "common sense ruling'?

Comment: Ok, you're right it is tricky — but successful saving throw can use up resources too, for example this: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/religion-traits/lessons-of-chaldira-chaldira-zuzaristan/ Thus, using up resources should not count as effect? I'll expand my answer when I'll have time to dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks! I also posted on their forum to see if *effect* ever got clarified (I doubt it) but maybe the community will have some more information or use-cases to build on